# Show image on the left and content on the right using ul li

Tags: content, columns

Well im looking for a way to do this.

In the index to show each post, with the "thumb" on the left and the content of the right using ul li to do so.(http://ae.tutsplus.com/ for example)

So far i figure out that with the usual loop i cant separate text and iamge, so im guessing i need to add some php to the mix?